# Can't run function in elixir shell after installing with `mix deps.get`

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying to install [`mint`](https://github.com/ericmj/mint) with `hex` as directed in the README.  However when I try to execute the example code I get an error:

```
9afa01708fef# iex  
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.9.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> {:ok, conn} = Mint.HTTP.connect(:http, "httpbin.org", 80)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Mint.HTTP.connect/3 is undefined (module Mint.HTTP is not available)
    Mint.HTTP.connect(:http, "httpbin.org", 80)
```

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me.  The solution was to start the shell with:

`iex -S mix`